# Spring 3.2.8 And Junit 4 Issue with JDK 8

Tags: spring, java-8, junit4

I have configured Junit 4 with Spring 3.2.8 where I have used JDK 8.
Here is my test controller class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebConfig.class })
public class TManagerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestManager  testManager ;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        this.testManager.getAll();
    }

}`
```

When I try to run application I'm getting this error:

> ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new
>   Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file
>   ././TManagerTest .java

When I search issue I found Spring 3.x support upto JDK 7. So it has to compile with JDK 7 but we can use JRE 8.

Is it true ? If yes my question is when I create classes with annotated `@Service`, `@Controller` and run application it works fine. Why does the error occur with junit only? If it is the case then it should not work with other than junit too.

If i want to use spring 3.2.8 , with jdk 8 .

Comment: your error comes from `ASM`. I wonder if you exclude and use a newer version of asm in your spring dependencies, would this work?

Comment: "Why i am getting error with junit only." - Find the source of the problem first and then this question probably answers itself. A likely reason is that tests have their own classpath to be able to add test-specific libraries (such as junit), maybe something is going wrong there.

Comment: @Gimby when i compile same code with jdk 7 with jre 8 it work fine

Comment: don't use Spring 3.x.x . It has reached EOL. [Look here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions)

Comment: @salman Yeah so the "it works" scenario is that you're running java 7 bytecode on Java 8. That is not unexpected when you take the error message into account.

Answer (score 1):

You need Spring 4 if you want compile code to Java 8 (target 1.8), but you can still run apps on Java 8 compiled to Java 7 if you run on Spring 3.2.x  .

As per [spring reference documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki):

> Note that the Java 8 bytecode level (-target 1.8, as required by
>   -source 1.8) is only fully supported as of Spring Framework 4.0. In particular, Spring 3.2 based applications need to be compiled with a
>   maximum of Java 7 as the target, even if they happen to be deployed
>   onto a Java 8 runtime. Please upgrade to Spring 4 for Java 8 based
>   applications.

Comment: My question is why my application code other than junit work fine. If this is a case than it should not work in application too

Comment: @salmanirfankhandu - I guess it's because the instance of your class is created and executed under a different "context". With JUnit, it's something like a simulation, not "real world". That's not an exact explanation, I'm aware. See my comment to your question.

Comment: not necessarily, I also have a legacy platform built with Spring 3.2 running on Java 8. With care it is possible.

Comment: @Gimby Tell me how it possible for me to sort issue as you said with care it possible